# I don't understand the results I obtained in a double-slit experiment, can someone help?

Tags: waves, double-slit-experiment

Today in my physics class I did an experiment where I held a double-slit diffraction grating up to my eye and viewed a light source. I observed a typical pattern of nodes and antinodes, with my eye acting as the screen.

As I moved away from the light source (keeping the distance between the grating and my eye constant), the distance between the nodes I saw increased.

My physics teacher cited Young's equation to explain this:

$$
x = \frac{\lambda L}{d}
$$

where $x$ is the distance between nodes, $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light, $d$ is distance between slits, and $L$ is the perpendicular distance from slits to screen.

But in my experiment, all I was changing was distance between the light source and the diffraction grating, which is not a variable in Young's equation.

Can someone explain this? I am confused.

Comment: I think that you need to provide some more information.  **1** Was the source a slit? **2** Was the source white light of one colour?  **3** Roughly what was the separation of the slit?  **4** Over what range was the source to slit distance?  **5** What was the slit to eye distance? **6** By how much did the fringe separation change with change of distance between source and slit.  **7** Other than their separation increasing did the fringes look different as you moved away from the source?

Comment: 1: The source was a small filament. 2: The effect was observed with both mixed white light and filtered red light. 3: 75 micrometres. 4: I observed the bands get further apart as I moved the slits from a few cm away to 2 metres away from the source. 5: a bit less than 10 cm. 6: Very noticeably. From a distance of a few cm away the fringes were like thin hairs close together, as I moved to 2 metres away they became much wider. 7: As I moved away from the source both the bright bands and the dark bands became wider. Other than that there were no changes as far as I can recall.